# Padrão de projetos

Tags: uml

Um analista me disse que eu preciso criar classes que calculem as prestações de contratos, porém eu percebi que este cálculo tem sempre os mesmos passos, mas a depender do tipo de contrato, alguns passos são feitos de formas diferentes. Os passos que pude identificar são: `CalcValorPrincipal`, `CalcTaxaAdministrativa` e CalcValorSeguro, após a execução dos mesmos o algoritmo soma tudo e retorna o valor total do contrato. Eu gostaria de saber qual o padrão de projeto recomendado para solucionar este problema e porque ele é o mais recomendado? Andei pesquisando e me parecia o modo de *template*, porém gostaria de uma ajuda de quem "manja" mais desta área.

Gostaria de um diagrama em UML deste problema utilizando o padrão recomendado para que possa ficar um pouco mais claro para mim.

Comment: Pelo que descreveu não parece ser Template. E nenhum destes padrões conhecidos. Mas posso estar engano porque a pergunta não tem informações suficientes. Mas pense o seguinte: resolva o problema, vai melhorando, depois você decide se um padrão pode se encaixar nele. Padrões são ótimos quando aplicados em momentos adequados por quem tem completo domínio deles. Padrões de projeto até parecem, mas não são receitas de bolo. *Design pattern* é uma ferramenta poderosa que exige grande responsabilidade no seu uso. Receita de bolo é copiar o que alguém fez sem entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Olá, Jeferson. Bem-vido ao [pt.so]! Sua pergunta é bem interessante, mas sem detalhes de como é a implementação fica difícil ajudar. Pela minha experiência no ramo financeiro, onde já trabalhei muito com cálculo de Principal e Valor Presente, digo que não existe um padrão de projeto (no sentido clássico) próprio para cálculos financeiros, porém você pode aplicar algumas boas práticas gerais. Uma delas é evitar incluir os objetos de domínio no meio dos cálculos. Crie rotinas de forma genérica com parâmetros explícitos e bem definidos. Se tiver as rotinas e puder postar, posso ajudar mais.

Answer (score 2):

Não entendo muito de UML, mas eu usaria o padrão Strategy que, como o nome diz, busca uma estrategia unica para cada tipo de situação, no caso de Contratos.
São geradas interfaces que mantém tudo "amarrado".

Uma interface que basicamente apenas obriga a quem implementa-la a calcular algo.

```
public interface Calculavel {
    public Double calcula();
}
```

Exemplos de implementação:

```
public class CalculoSeguroTipoX implements Calculavel{
    @Override
    public Double calcula() {
        //Aqui está a forma de calculo...
        return null;
    }
}
public class CalculoTaxaAdministrativaTipoB implements Calculavel{
    @Override
    public Double calcula() {
        //Aqui está a forma de calculo...
        return null;
    }
}
public class CalculoValorPrincipalTipoY implements Calculavel {
    @Override
    public Double calcula() {
        //Aqui está a forma de calculo...
        return null;
    }
}
```

Temos também a interface Contrato que obriga a todo contrato ter diversos tipos de implementações que são calculaveis.

```
public interface Contrato {
    public Calculavel getCalcTaxaAdministrativa();
    public Calculavel getCalcValorPrincipal();
    public Calculavel getCalcValorSeguro();
}
```

E por fim uma implementação de um contrato:

```
public class ContratoPessoaFisica implements Contrato{

    @Override
    public Calculavel getCalcTaxaAdministrativa() {
        return new CalculoTaxaAdministrativaTipoB();
    }

    @Override
    public Calculavel getCalcValorPrincipal() {
        return new CalculoValorPrincipalTipoY();
    }

    @Override
    public Calculavel getCalcValorSeguro() {
        return new CalculoSeguroTipoX();
    }
}
```

Espero que eu tenha ajudado.